# How should I write an OptaPlanner Planning Entity PlanningVariable Annotation in Grails?

Tags: grails, optaplanner

I tried to convert my OptaPlanner code from Java to Grails. Everything else is fine except I'm stuck when I changed the Planning Entity class into a Groovy file. Then Error message with this would show:

> startup failed: F:\Users\Administrator\Documents\workspace-ggts-3.2.0.RELEASE\spa\src\groovy\optaplanner\domain\AllocationEntity.groovy: 15: Annotation list attributes must use Groovy notation [el1, el2] in @org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.variable.PlanningVariable @ line 15, column 48. able(valueRangeProviderRefs = {"projects ^ 1 error

And my Intellij IDEA also would prompt an error message when I hover over the line `@PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = {"projectsRange"})` with red warning highlight under `{"projectsRange"}`, and the error message is this:

> Cannot assign 'Class' to 'String[]'

I wish to use Groovy instead of Java for the GORM feature to query database. But how can I fix this error so I can use the Planning Entity as a Groovy class?

Answer (score 4):

Most Java code is valid Groovy code, but there are a few exceptions, mostly when dealing with curly braces. Closures are defined in Groovy as a code block inside of curly braces, e.g.

```
def foo = {
   ...
}
```

so other uses of curly braces will confuse the Groovy parser. In most cases you just use regular braces instead. In this case your annotation list should be

```
@PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = ["projectsRange"])
```

Comment: Thank you. After changing for "[]" Intellij IDEA really stopped complaining about it. But still the program didn't work. Eventually I kept the Entity class as a java file which invokes another class in groovy in order to use Grails' GORM feature while making my program work at all. I'm unsure which worked wrong here.

But the tip on using "[]" instead of "{}" is still helpful which can help me converting groovy to java in the future. Thank you very much!